# How to install github python files which pip installation is not provided?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I want to install https://github.com/opendoor-labs/pyfin package in windows 10, but no pip installation method is provided in the page. I use vs-code python-3.9.10 and all my libraries are installed in a virtual environment. The git address of all files is https://github.com/opendoor-labs/pyfin.git. but I don't know how to download and install directly to the (venv). Is there any easy way to install and import it to my code? I tried 'pip install pyfin', but it installed other library included in this page : https://pypi.org/project/pyfin/ which is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First activate your venv.
(activate it using the `.\venv\Scripts\activate` command.)

The run `pip install git+https://github.com/your/repo`

Comment: I tried both, at first It mentioned that I don't have git installed, then I installed it from https://git-scm.com/download/win page, I tried again but I get another error setup.py", line 11, in <module>      readme = open('README.rst').read():"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst' "